# Преобразование типов и конструктор преобразования

Tags: c++

Полностью ли эквивалентны две строки ниже

```
auto s1 = Foo(x);
auto s2 = (Foo)x;
```

С одной стороны T(x) это конструктор по стандарту, а с другой http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast говорит, что строки идентичны.

Comment: С чего бы? Первое - это вызывание по конструктору, а второй - кастинг в тип. Другой вопрос это то что если Foo имеет и позволяет такое использование...

Comment: Оформите как ответ, по вашим словами T(x) != (T)x - а вот как это доказать ?

Comment: Сравните http://ideone.com/LD9SBU и http://ideone.com/itny5Q

Comment: @Harry сравнил - строки в обоих случаев в имеют одну и ту же реализацию.

Comment: Нет- в первом случае закомментирован конструктор

Comment: @Harry так смысл показать разницу между s1 и s2 строками - а вы показали совсем другое

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov: Какое еще "вызывание по конструктору"? Где это в языке С++ вы нашли такое понятие, как "вызывание по конструктору"?

Comment: Интересно звучит :) Примерно как "Нужно показать, что все не так, как на самом деле". Я показал конкретный пример; если хотите - доказывайте, что компиляторы работают неправильно...

Comment: @Harry Возможно я вас не так понял. Вопрос чем отличается a и b - вы показываете, что fn1(a) == fn1(b) и fn2(a) == fn2(b). Это не доказывает, что a == b или a != b . Так проще понять Вам, что вы сделали?

Answer (score 2):

Да, полностью эквивалентны.

Первое - это явное приведение типа в функциональной нотации, второе - это явное приведение типа в каст-нотации.

Спецификация языка открытым текстом говорит, что если явное приведение типа в функциональной нотации имеет *ровно один аргумент* (т.е. ровно одно выражение внутри `()`), то оно строго эквивалентно явному приведению типа в каст-нотации.

> **5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation) [expr.type.conv]**
>
> **1** [...] If the expression list is a single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression (5.4). [...]

То есть по определению выражение вида `Foo(x)` сразу же рассматривается языком С++ как выражение `(Foo) x`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Конструкция:

   ```
   auto s1 = Foo(x);
   ```

   вызывает *конструктор* того типа, который имеет принимающая сторона. То есть:

   ```
   Foo::Foo(const T& other)
   ```
2. А конструкция:

   ```
   auto s2 = (Foo)x;
   ```

   в свою очередь вызывает *оператор приведения типа* отправляющей стороны. То есть:

   ```
   Bar::operator Foo(const Foo& other)
   ```

Comment: Нет, не верно. С обоих случаях семантика выражения одна та же. В обоих случаях совершенно одинаковым образом будут рассматриваться и преобразования через конструктор, и преобразования через операторы приведения типа, и неявные преобразования. Способ приведения будет выбираться по общим правилам overload resolution с одним и тем же набором кандидатов. Т.е. способ приведения в обоих случаях всегда будет выбран один и тот же. Никакого предпочтения конструкторам (в первом случае), или операторам приведения типа (во втором) не отдается.

Comment: Гляньте, поиграйтесь с http://ideone.com/LD9SBU и http://ideone.com/itny5Q

Answer (score 0):

В обоих случаях компилятор постарается сначала найти подходящий конструктор у класса Foo с одним обязательным параметром, такой конструктор что в него можно было бы передать `x`, и вызовет его. А если нет такого подходящего конструктора, то для типа, к которому относится `x`, начнет искать оператор преобразования в тип Foo, и вызовет его. Если и его нет, то компилятор выдаст ошибку.

У простых типов (`int`, `char`, `float` и т.п.) , можно условно считать, что есть конструкторы копирования, а также операторы преобразования в другие простые типы

Ответ: строчки эквивалентны.

Comment: Если быть предельно педантичным, то компилятор *всегда* будет пользоваться каким-то конструктором класса `Foo` (а не только "сначала") - от этого никуда не деться. Вопрос только в том, какой это будет конструктор. Если `Foo` умеет конструироваться напрямую из `x`, то выбран будет именно этот конструктор. А если нет, то будет выбран какой-то другой конструктор `Foo` и `x` будет неявно сконвертирован к типу параметра этого конструктора.